# How to compare time property in each object group in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, reduce

I do have a array of objects, which each group of objects need to filtered based on thier time property, and in output it should only return ithems which have less then 1 minute time difference and remove those which have more then 1 minute time difference ( With same format and grouped ).

Update : time difference between each consecutive transaction should be less than 1 minute.

```
var grouped = [
[
    {"id":29,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-580,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-05T20:01:18.000Z"},
    {"id":18,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-580,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-05T20:01:18.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":38,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"restaurant","amount":-970,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-17T19:52:46.000Z"},
    {"id":22,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"restaurant","amount":-970,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-17T19:52:46.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":31,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z"},
    {"id":30,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z"},
    {"id":33,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:57:05.000Z"},
    {"id":19,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-07T09:54:21.000Z"},
    {"id":32,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"},
    {"id":35,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:58:06.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":14,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z"},
    {"id":15,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z"},
    {"id":13,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z"},
    {"id":9,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z"},
    {"id":2,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-01T12:34:00.000Z"},
    {"id":5,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-02T09:25:20.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":39,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"fitness_club","amount":-610,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-22T11:54:10.000Z"},
    {"id":24,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"fitness_club","amount":-610,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-22T11:54:10.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":41,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-450,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-23T19:13:10.000Z"},
    {"id":26,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-450,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-23T19:13:10.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":1,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-02-25T08:00:00.000Z"},
    {"id":27,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-04-25T08:00:00.000Z"},
    {"id":16,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-03-25T08:10:00.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":20,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"internet_shop","amount":-1650,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-08T21:36:41.000Z"},
    {"id":36,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"internet_shop","amount":-1650,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-08T21:36:41.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":39,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-70,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-15T09:12:20.000Z"},
    {"id":23,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-70,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-15T09:12:20.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":40,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-850,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-20T18:51:31.000Z"},
    {"id":25,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-850,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-20T18:51:31.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":17,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1870,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-05T10:24:30.000Z"},
    {"id":28,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1870,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-05T10:24:30.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":21,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1690,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-10T18:14:10.000Z"},
    {"id":37,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1690,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-10T18:14:10.000Z"}
  ]
]
```

This is what I tried, but this one still have those items with more then 1 minute ( Even some of them have time difference more then 1 month! )

```
var result = grouped.map((tr, i) => {
        return tr.filter((t, j) => {
          if (grouped[i][j - 1]) {
            var d1 = Date.parse(t.time);
            var d2 = Date.parse(grouped[i][j - 1].time);
            return (d1 - d2) <= 60000;
          }
          return true;
        });
      });
```

And just before I run above code, I sort it by time like this :

```
  grouped.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.time > a.time
    });
```

UPDATE :

Basiclly the expected output of the given grouped of object should be something like this :

```
var expectedOutput = [
[
    {"id":31,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z"},
    {"id":30,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z"},
    {"id":32,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"}
],
[
    {"id":14,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z"},
    {"id":15,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z"},
    {"id":13,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z"}
]
]
```

Really not sure where I did wrong, can anyone help me on this? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ‘items which have less then 1 minute time difference’. Does that mean 1 minute from the first element, 1 min from earliest, 1 min from previous? Largest group within a single minute?

Comment: time difference between each consecutive transaction should be less than 1 minute.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I update the question, the expected object should be something like that, only two array length should be remain, since when we compare consecutively, these are only items with less the 1 minute time difference

Comment: If you're comparing to the previous element in the group, you should probably sort by the `.time` property first.

Comment: @user3297291 Yes, I already did sort before handling the comparing :   grouped.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.time > a.time
        });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given data structure an approach twice needs to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) a list. Firstly the outer list structure that groups lists of account-items. Each of these lists firstly should be sorted by the time stamp (time property) of it's account-items. The second, reducing, step finds valid ranges of items by comparing the time offset in between a current item and it's previous and next sibling in case they are available. Only items of a (strictly) valid range will be collected.

```js
var grouped = [[
 {"id":29,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-580,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-05T20:01:18.000Z"},
 {"id":18,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-580,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-05T20:01:18.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":38,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"restaurant","amount":-970,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-17T19:52:46.000Z"},
 {"id":22,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"restaurant","amount":-970,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-17T19:52:46.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":31,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z"},
 {"id":30,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z"},
 {"id":33,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:57:05.000Z"},
 {"id":19,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-07T09:54:21.000Z"},
 {"id":32,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z"},
 {"id":35,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-90,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-07T09:58:06.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":14,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z"},
 {"id":15,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z"},
 {"id":13,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z"},
 {"id":9,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-04T07:14:20.000Z"},
 {"id":2,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-01T12:34:00.000Z"},
 {"id":5,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-50,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-03-02T09:25:20.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":39,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"fitness_club","amount":-610,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-22T11:54:10.000Z"},
 {"id":24,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"fitness_club","amount":-610,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-22T11:54:10.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":41,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-450,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-23T19:13:10.000Z"},
 {"id":26,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"cinema","amount":-450,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-23T19:13:10.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":1,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-02-25T08:00:00.000Z"},
 {"id":27,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-04-25T08:00:00.000Z"},
 {"id":16,"sourceAccount":"company_x","targetAccount":"my_account","amount":10000,"category":"salary","time":"2018-03-25T08:10:00.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":20,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"internet_shop","amount":-1650,"category":"other","time":"2018-04-08T21:36:41.000Z"},
 {"id":36,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"internet_shop","amount":-1650,"category":"other","time":"2018-05-08T21:36:41.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":39,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-70,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-05-15T09:12:20.000Z"},
 {"id":23,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"coffee_shop","amount":-70,"category":"eating_out","time":"2018-04-15T09:12:20.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":40,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-850,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-20T18:51:31.000Z"},
 {"id":25,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-850,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-20T18:51:31.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":17,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1870,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-05T10:24:30.000Z"},
 {"id":28,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1870,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-05T10:24:30.000Z"}
], [
 {"id":21,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1690,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-04-10T18:14:10.000Z"},
 {"id":37,"sourceAccount":"my_account","targetAccount":"supermarket","amount":-1690,"category":"groceries","time":"2018-05-10T18:14:10.000Z"}
]];

function orderByTimeProperty(a, b) {
  return ((a.time < b.time && -1) || (a.time > b.time && 1) || 0);
}

function collectListItemsWithLessThanOneMinuteDelta(collector, item, idx, list) {
  function isValidTimeDelta(a, b) {
    return (Math.abs((new Date(b)).getTime() - (new Date(a)).getTime()) < timeDelta);
  }
  var
    timeDelta = (1000 * 60),
    prevItem  = list[idx - 1],
    nextItem  = list[idx + 1];
  if (
    (prevItem && nextItem && isValidTimeDelta(prevItem.time, item.time) && isValidTimeDelta(item.time, nextItem.time))
    || (nextItem && isValidTimeDelta(item.time, nextItem.time))
    || (prevItem && isValidTimeDelta(prevItem.time, item.time))
  ) {
    collector.push(item);
  }
  return collector;
}

function collectGroupedListItemsWithLessThanOneMinuteDelta(collector, list) {
  list = list.sort(orderByTimeProperty).reduce(collectListItemsWithLessThanOneMinuteDelta, []);

  if (list.length >= 1) {
    collector.push(list);
  }
  return collector;
}

var list = grouped.reduce(collectGroupedListItemsWithLessThanOneMinuteDelta, []);

console.log('reduced list : ', list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @peter, your answer helped me a lot to understand the probelm. greate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArr = [];
grouped.forEach(function(elements){
    let res = compareTime(elements)
    if(res.length > 0)
    newArr.push(res)
})
console.log(newArr)

function compareTime(value) {
    let newArr = []
    let existCheck = []
    for(let i = 0; i < value.length; i ++) {
        let iTime = Date.parse(value[i].time)
        for(let j=i + 1; j < value.length; j++) {
            let jTime = Date.parse(value[j].time)
            let timeCompare = iTime - jTime 
            if(timeCompare < 60000 && timeCompare > -60000){
                if(!existCheck.includes(value[i].time)) {
                    newArr.push(value[i])
                    existCheck.push(value[i].time)
                }
                if(!existCheck.includes(value[j].time)) {
                    newArr.push(value[j])
                    existCheck.push(value[j].time)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
```

> Output::

```
[ [ { id: 31,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -90,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-05-07T09:55:10.000Z' },
    { id: 30,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -90,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-05-07T09:54:21.000Z' },
    { id: 32,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -90,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-05-07T09:56:09.000Z' },
    { id: 33,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -90,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-05-07T09:57:05.000Z' } ],
  [ { id: 14,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -50,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-04-01T10:24:40.000Z' },
    { id: 15,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -50,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-04-01T10:25:10.000Z' },
    { id: 13,
      sourceAccount: 'my_account',
      targetAccount: 'coffee_shop',
      amount: -50,
      category: 'eating_out',
      time: '2018-04-01T10:24:00.000Z' } ] ]
```